# Testing power consumption

Tags: ups, electrical-power

I'm buying an UPS for the new server. As always, money is short, so I need to buy one which is sufficient, but not needlessly overpowered. The server has a 900 W power supply, but the retailer says he doubts it would ever draw over 300 watts. I went out and bought an "energy meter" today, which can show the consumption, but now I need to test how much I can get it to use.

When starting up, the max usage was around 230 W. How can I test the max usage? Is there software with the only usage of making the computer work a lot? The server has a single Xeon W3565 (3.2 GHz) processor, 24 GB RAM and 6 SAS disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To saturate all resources of a server, just run at the same time:

- bonnie++
- prime95
- BOINC/primegrid
- memtest86+
- netperf/ipperf
- Linux kernel compilation
- ping flood the BMC interface

Comment: See also: http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=486495

Comment: Prime95 managed to get it to draw almost 300 W. I think I'll be fine with that 1000 VA APC...